# Rails With MongoDB - Error On Bundle Update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, rubygems, bundle

I have installed mongodb and rails on a CentOS vps.

```
rails new myapp --skip-active-record
```

In my Gemfile I have:

```
gem 'mongoid', github: 'mongoid/mongoid'
gem 'bson_ext', '~> 1.8.6'
```

And then I ran:

```
bundle install
```

But I got an error message:

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:172:in `security_policies': uninitialized constant Gem::Security::Policies (NameError)
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:175:in `<class:CLI>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:6:in `<module:Bundler>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/cli.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
        from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.3.5/bin/bundle:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
        from /usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
```

How can I resolve this? Thanks..

Comment: The issue is neither in mongo or mongoid. I bet you will get the same error if you will try to run bundle install on non-mongo app. Go install `libssl` package. It should help you.

Comment: thanks @Ash Wilson for edited my question
@user2422869 : i've installed openssl.message when i tried install openssl `Package openssl-devel-0.9.8e-26.el5_9.1.i386 already installed and latest version`